# Is there a function to know the useableSize of a view?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar, xcode4.5

It must take into account:

statusBar (which can be 40 points if you have hot spot)
TabBar
NavigationBar.

Basically at viewDidLoad I see that my view has a size of 320*480.

I wonder where did iOS decide that as the screen size of my screen. I use UIStoryBoard.

So, on viewDidLoad, I intended to resize that.

I am not even sure if this is the right approach.

Note: the issue I am facing doesn't seem to happen if I do not use storyBoard.

At viewDidLoad, when I use XIB, the content of self.view is correct, namely 416, instead of 480, due to UInavigationController and UITabBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding the `UIViewController viewWillLayoutSubviews` method. The view's frame will be set by then.

In the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method, the view controller's main view is the size you need to know. It has been adjusted for status bars and nav bars and tools bars and tab bars. It also takes into account orientation. There is no single method where you can ask what the size will be. Besides, there is no need to ask such a question. Create all the subviews you want in `viewDidLoad`. But lay them out based on the view's size in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: is this called before or after viewDidLoad?

Comment: After. It would be hard to layout the sub views if the main view wasn't loaded yet.

Comment: +1 That is correct and it does solve my problem. It simply doesn't answer the question though. I'll select this in a week when there is no other better answer.

Comment: It does answer the question. In the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method, the view controller's main view is the size you need to know. It has been adjusted for status bars and nav bars and tools bars and tab bars. It also takes into account orientation. There is no single method where you can ask what the size will be. Besides, there is no need to ask such a question. Create all the subviews you want in `viewDidLoad`. But lay them out based on the view's size in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: I checked this as the answer. You need to put your last comment on the answer.

Comment: It doesn't take into account the fact that your controller may be a child controller though.

Comment: and I think there is indeed a function to know that. Your method works too.

Comment: Something along using window or something. However it may only take into account status bar. I saw that once in stackoverflow.